# If my chmod permissions have been reduced to 444 what can I do to rectify this situation?

Tags: linux

Always been wondering about this, I figure some hackers out there probably know. I did it on a VM and couldn't figure out what to do for the life of me.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -e 'chmod 0755, "/bin/chmod";'
```

This will fix it if you are root. Most unix and linux based OS's have perl installed  and available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Boring option: mount that partition from a live CD/different machine and chmod your chmod...

If you have python installed, intact *and* have some already executable python script you can edit, you could hijack it to call [os.chmod](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm). Or similar call in any still executable thing that can do system calls.

Comment: you wouldn't even need an executable python script; you can just run `python -c ...`.  (if python won't execute, an executable script won't help you either.)

Comment: Why the script you can edit? Just sudo python is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp /bin/ls new-chmod && cp /bin/chmod new-chmod && ./new-chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

First, make a new (must be new, so cp will copy permissions) file, which is a copy of an existing executable file (/bin/ls).  Then copy the contents of chmod over the new executable file (cp won't copy permissions to an existing file).  Then use this new executable chmod to make /bin/chmod executable.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to [Single User Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_user_mode) (`init 1`) and you should be able to restore your permissions.

In effect (though not exactly true), this logging is as a "super-root" user.